# RAILS - Facebook login without facebook confirmation page using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I'm here to discover if what I want to do is possible or not. Can I connect to facebook using a rails method without passing through the facebook confirmation page?

I want to implement an app that should have a facebook acc/pass and I need to send a comment in a timeline, but I don't want to allow the facebook page. I want to do something automatic.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing yet. I'm still looking a way to do what I need, but I only find how to do using the page of the facebook to the user pass the account and password. I need something automatic, that given a pre-determinated account and password I send a post, like a "firing email".

Answer (score 0):

No, the facebook api in rails is built in a way that you can't directly login to your site using facebook. This is restricted for facebook authorization issues and it's terms and conditions.

If the user wants to allow access, he’ll have to log into his account (still on the facebook page) before being redirect back to your application. In the background Facebook will return an access token that your application will use to get access to the users data.

Check [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/) for more details.

Comment: OK! I already heard that with twitter this is possible, this it true?

Thanks for your patient!

Comment: No, it isn't possible with twitter too. The only way possible is if you are already `logged in` on facebook or twitter itself only then you will be directed without confirmation page from your application.